# How to solve this TAC problem

Tags: taxonomy-terms

TAC is installed (Taxonomy Access Control). There's a taxonomy vocabulary called "TAC Roles" that determines which users can view which content. In this vocabulary are two roles: "trusted user" and "exclusive access user". There are also roles with the same name.

Now the thing I want is that users can only see the content if they have all the roles associated with the TAC Roles vocabulary. I.e.: if a piece of content has both terms selected only users that have both roles should be able to see this node.

TAC is now set up that authenticated users are denied both Exclusive Access as Trusted access. The trusted user has Exclusive Access on Denied but Trusted access on Allow. The Exclusive Access user has Exclusive Access on Allow but Trusted access on Denied.

The problem I have now is that if a user has both roles and a piece of content has both terms associated the node will not be visible to this user.

Comment: You'll need to hack TAC, I'm afraid. Or post it in their issue queue as a feature request. But hacking it seems a faster way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm afraid that puts a dead end on this functionality for my website then..